# How to change color of shapes in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

So I'm trying to change the color of this image.
What I did is that I used Magic Wand tool to select the shape and when I tried to 
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to change its color but the problem is that the selected pixels is filled with the pure color. I mean I want to have the edges of the shape to have some less opacity per the image to be smoother.

[image]

And the output will be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Kindly explain why it's downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Try this way instead. There's no need to make a selection for this to work:

1. Create anew Hue/Saturation adjustment layer, and check the "colorize" option.
2. Adjust the sliders until you get the colour you want.
3. Then Alt+click between the two layers to clip the Hue/Saturation adjustment only to the layer below.

Example here:

[image: Using a Hue/Saturation Adjustment Layer]

Comment: So is there any way where I can just put the Hex value? I'm looking for the value of #cc3333 and it doesn't work.  https://postimg.org/image/6vvgwumx5/

Comment: @leonardeveloper If the shape has transparency, you could hit the pixel lock on the layer, then fill it with a hex colour - using Edit > Fill.  In fact probably the best way to do this would simply be to recreate your own graphic - using the shape tool.  It's not exactly hard to draw a circle with a cross in the middle.  Then you can fill the circle with any colour you want. See here: http://imgur.com/a/hc5PW

Comment: The HSL value is not working when I tried it. It's a sprite images so it'll take some time if I did creating a new one. I'm new to this.

Comment: @leonardeveloper It took me about one minute to recreate the icon, and add the fill colour you want. These are skills worth learning. It might take you a while the first time, but you will learn to get quicker.

Comment: If you want a specific color you could use a clipping layer.

Answer (score 0):

First time posting on here so let me know if not hitting the mark.

So select your layer in the layers panel (shown at top of image included), click on the 'Lock transparent pixels' option towards the top of the layers panel (shown in middle of image included with hover tip) then fill the item with the colour you need and selected in your foreground swatch using alt/option and backspace keys on Mac (bottom of included image shows the pixels colouring/feathering as you wish I believe). Let me know if any issues.

[image: 3 Steps]

Comment: Almost there, just one thing see https://postimg.org/image/li10irqp5/ the edges is still have the original color.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick key alternative, you can select your layer in the layers panel and just hit SHIFT + ALT/OPTION + BACKSPACE and this will Fill Layer with whichever colour you have in your foreground swatch. To do this through the top menu navigation  again select your layer in the layers panel then go to EDIT along the top of your window FILL... then in the pop up box select whether you want to fill with the foreground or background colour and ensure the PRESERVE TRANSPARENCY option is ticked.